# How to use pyramid route in the sub module case?

Tags: python, routes, pyramid

I want to add a new route to the current project. The project's structure like:

```
myprj
- module1
-- __init__.py
- module2
-- __init__.py
- module3
-- __init__.py
```

I add this to `myprj/module1/__init__.py`

```
config.add_route('locale', '/locale')
```

Then add a method in `myprj/module1/subscribers.py`

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(route_name='locale')
def set_locale_cookie(request):
    print('OK')
```

When I access my project by: http://myprj.com/locale, it can't find the `locale` path. Why?

Comment: How are you doing your config.scan()? Maybe you have to manually scan the individual module folders

Comment: @fatfantasma This due to my special project. I have fixed it in another module. Thank you all the same.